# How to compute the Google Query's data field?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

how can I compute QUERY's data attribute to make data range dynamic?

**More details**: I have a spreadsheet with multiple worksheets incl. a separate "summary" one. Here, a couple of queries are aggregating data from these multiple sheets. All fine. But: any time I add/remove a sheet, I will have to update all queries manually - which is quite cumbersome. So I created a small script that returns the names of all worksheets. Nice.

What I have trouble with: how can I make QUERY() accept these worksheet names? It returns `#value`.

- originally:
  `= QUERY({'sheet 1'!$A:$C; 'sheet 2'!$A:$C}; "SELECT SUM(Col2), ...")  //works.`
- with script:
  `= QUERY(getSheetNames(); "SELECT SUM(Col2), ...")  //#value error`
- add script to cell and referencing cell:
  `= QUERY(A1; "SELECT SUM(Col2), ...")  //#value error`
- custom function:
  `getSheetNames()` currently returns `"{'sheet 1'!$A:$C; 'sheet 2'!$A:$C}"`

```
function getSheetNames() {
  var out = "";
  var columns = "!$A:$C";
  var apostrophe = "'";
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    
    for (var i = 1 ; i < sheets.length; i++) {
      out += apostrophe + sheets[i].getName() + apostrophe + columns + "; ";
    }
  
  out = "{" + out.slice(0, -2) + "}";
  return out;
}
```

Many thanks for help!

Comment: Can you provide the code related to `getSheetNames()`? Most probably the problem is `getSheetNames()` returns a string, and `QUERY` expects a range of cells. Considering your situation, I'd suggest making all of this (QUERY included) a custom function, and not calling the result of the custom function in a regular formula. Is there a reason you cannot do that? If you think this can be a valid workaround, but you're unsure how to do this, consider providing the full `QUERY` formula, I'd consider posting an answer explaining this.

Comment: Hey @lamblichus, many thanks. Not returning a string a very is a great idea and might do the trick! What kind of type is it supposed to be returned? I'll post the `getSheetNames()` above.
I would rather not wrap everything in a custom function for the sake of maintainability as there a several people working on this sheet.

Comment: its easier to generate the formula as a text string and then with script convert that string into actual formula

Comment: `I would rather not wrap everything in a custom function for the sake of maintainability` You could have all the information that might change as parameters of your custom function. To do it the way you want, you would probably need [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) but I don't think it can be done if you don't know how many sheets your formula will return. I actually think having everything in a custom formula would make maintenance easier.

Comment: @player0 I don't think you can set a formula with a custom function (methods like `setValue` or `setFormula` cannot be used).

Comment: @Iamblichus made me think about string and cell ranges. Still, can't get it working. Tried `= QUERY(INDIRECT(getSheetNames()); "SELECT SUM(Col2), ...") ` but GSheets still returns an error `Parameter 1 of the "INDIRECT" function has the value "{'sheet 1'!$A:$C; 'sheet 2'!$A:$C}". This is not a valid cell/range reference.`

Comment: @00willson Yes, you would need to use `INDIRECT` for each sheet, otherwise it cannot work. But since you don't know how many sheets you're going to call, this becomes quite tricky. I don't think it makes sense to use regular formulas on the custom function and I'd very much recommend using a custom function for everything.